# How to get the type of values in a map in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I cannot find a solution for this anywhere.

Lets say I have

```
type ObjectRecord = { [key: number]: SomeType }
```

Now I can have another type

```
type ValueInObjectRecord = ObjectRecord[number] // SomeType
```

What if I want to do the same thing with a map?

```
type MapRecord = Map<number, SomeType>
```

```
type ValueInMapRecord = MapRecord[number] // does not work!
```

Comment: I won't post it as an answer because TypeScript is *incredibly* rich and it's easy to miss things, but I'm about 98% sure it doesn't have something that handles this (yet). You're trying to extract the type argument that was used when creating a concrete type (`MapRecord`) from a generic type (`Map`). I think you'll have to go the other way: `type ValueInMapRecord = SomeType; type MapRecord = Map<number, ValueInMapRecord>;` But again, I could be wrong -- and hope that I am. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will want to make use of [type inference in conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) / `infer`:

```
type SomeType = { foo: string }

type MapRecord = Map<number, SomeType>

type ValueInMapRecord = MapRecord extends Map<any, infer I> ? I : never
// type ValueInMapRecord = { foo: string; }
```

This is a common way to retrieve type constituents and would also have worked with `ObjectRecord`:

```
type ValueInObjectRecord = ObjectRecord extends {[key:number]: infer I} ? I : never
// type ValueInObjectRecord = { foo: string; }
```

[Playground code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXNAvFA3lAZnOALigGdgAnASwDsBzKAXwCgnRIoBZAQzACUIAxnHIATKJm5gAPNQCuCAEYRyAGliIUaAHws20AGpcANrIgBJapP5DR4zj2vCxEAB7AI1ESXvSu1EGo0uMpQZlpQAPyhUMTUEABuykwA9MlQelCGJuaWDoJOdjj4RKQUNLQA3Iy6aFAA8goAVoLAjraYOADaANYQILHySuQAusTwSKjszBlZphYNzQKt+e31TS1tzm4eXthQPX0DisqjUEEhZoyR0bEJSanptbM5CxsrYh14BMRkVHRVDCAA)

Comment: Aha, I've come across this before. Seems pretty good for maps. But isn't this kind of bad to do with `ObjectRecord`? Since the point is to be dynamic, but if you were to change `ObjectRecord` you would likely also have to change `ValueInObjectRecord`? I feel like I can accept that for a Map but for an Object I'd rather go with the other syntax

Comment: I guess, there is no clear right or wrong - feel free to choose the variant, which best fits the use case at hand. I absolutely agree with you going with lookup types (`ObjectRecord[number]`) for object literal types like `ObjectRecord`, as more concise. Mentioned alternative was shown to demonstrate, `infer` is a swiss army knife in terms of type constituent resolution :-).